# ArcGIS tutorial data for classroom use?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license, arctutor

I am responsible for preparing a GIS lab, and I was wondering if there is any license restriction for using the tutorial data in ArcGIS (ArcTutor) for classroom use like this? (attribution, modification etc.)

I searched around, and found ArcGIS tutorials being hosted on outside website like Duke library
http://library.duke.edu/data/collections/gis/esri/tutorials

Also googling ArcGIS tutorial license doesn't show much. Results are mostly about the license manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you need data for an arcGIS tutorial, may I recommend [Utah's Automatic Geographic Reference Center (AGRC)](http://gis.utah.gov/data/) as an alternative? If you need Census data, the [TIGER files](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html) provide an attractive alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the Data provided with ArcGIS for Desktop is discussed in your Esri License Agreement (C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\License\EULA.pdf).

I am not a lawyer and so will not offer an opinion on whether the uses you describe are allowed or not.

If you read that and are unsure, then I think you should contact Esri to describe your planned use and ask whether you are OK to proceed.